# WrapAll() on multiple classes with multiple appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

Lets say this is my HTML

```html
<ul class="products>
<li class="product">
<div class="product-title></div>
<div class="product-thumbnail></div>
<div class="product-price></div>
<div class="product-discription></div>
</li>
<li class="product">
<div class="product-title></div>
<div class="product-thumbnail></div>
<div class="product-price></div>
<div class="product-discription></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to wrap `.product-thumbnail` and `.product-price` in

```
<div class="left"></div>
```

Like this

```html
  <ul class="products>
       <li class="product">
        <div class="product-title></div>
        <div class="left">
         <div class="product-thumbnail></div>
         <div class="product-price></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-discription></div>
       </li>

       <li class="product">
        <div class="product-title></div>
        <div class="left">
         <div class="product-thumbnail></div>
         <div class="product-price></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-discription></div>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

This code does the trick if I had only one list item

```
$(".product-thumbnail, .product-price").wrapAll("<div class='left'></div>");
```

I've tried an `each()` on `.product-thubnail` and `.product-price` but without results..

Does anyone know how I could do this or how it could be done with `each()`?

Comment: You need to tidy up your code examples and replace all the missing closing quotes you omitted

Comment: that's how question should be ask . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the `.product-title` using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and combine with the immediate next element using [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/add) method.

```js
$('.product-title').each(function() {
  $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="left"></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="product-price"></div>
    <div class="product-discription"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="product-price"></div>
    <div class="product-discription"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Or iterate over the `li` and get both classes within the element by providing the context.

```js
$('.product').each(function() {
  $('.product-title,.product-thumbnail', this).wrapAll('<div class="left"></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li class="product">
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="product-price"></div>
    <div class="product-discription"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="product-price"></div>
    <div class="product-discription"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks!, The iterate over the list items works great! I will accept your answer if the 4 minutes are over :)

Comment: thank you for your great answer. why you used `this` in your second example ?

Comment: @Mahi : for finding element within the `this` context ..... which search element within the current `li`